# Using cell value to determine directory for text import through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded a macro allowing me to import a text file and delimit it with "|". However, this macro will need to run many times during a day. The text file it is importing has a timestamp that changes at the end of it. I want to reference a cell with my vba code that has the cell directory and changes based on current time.

```
Sub DataImport()
Dim LResult As String

LResult = Dir(ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Select)

ActiveSheet.Range("B8:G2000").Cells.ClearContents
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;LResult", Destination:= _
         Range("$B$8"))
        .Name = "CustomerEngagement_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The top part is me trying to make the cell a directory in LResult and referenced it in the import...

Thoughts? I am currenlty looking into FileSystemOperator to see if I can use that.

Comment: Is the timestamp in the filename? It would help if you could show an example.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir()` only returns the filename, so you'll need to add the directory path in order to pass the file into the QueryTable creation.

Something like this (untested)

```
Sub DataImport()

Const FOLDER_PATH as string = "C:\data\example\"
Dim LResult As String

'check for a .txt file with a name containing the value from C6
LResult = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*" & ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value & "*.txt")

if Len(LResult)=0 Then
    msgbox "No matching file located"
    Exit sub
end if

ActiveSheet.Range("B8:G2000").Cells.ClearContents
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "TEXT;" & FOLDER_PATH & LResult, _
                                    Destination:= Range("$B$8"))
'...


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this question is still relevant, but the solution is:

```
LResult = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value
```

And:

```
"TEXT;" & LResult, Destination:= _
```